# CodePen React Code failing to load my gradient background

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, codepen

I'll try to keep this as descriptive as possible.
Link to CodePen: https://codepen.io/Yosharu/pen/morErw

My problem is that my background (and several other CSS stuff) is failing to load in my code, leaving the background white and the text off centered and everything.

Here is the line with my gradient background: 66

```css
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #77c9d4, #57bc90);
```

Here is what it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the React attribute `className` in your render() function for the body element.

Example:

```html
<div className="body">...</div>
```

This applies to all elements where you need to define a class. React requires this special attribute to render properly.

[ReactJS className](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname)

> To specify a CSS class, use the className attribute. This applies to all regular DOM and SVG elements like <div>, <a>, and others.

[Updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/sforsberg/pen/qvqrpP)

Answer (score 0):

'class' is a reserved word in JavaScript. To apply a css class you need to use `className`